# How do I solve "Server requires packet signing to be enabled" when mounting a Windows share?

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

Consider:

```
11:12 dev@ubuntu ~/qsr  (build-0.3)$ dmesg
[57392.897482] CIFS VFS: Server requires packet signing to be enabled in /proc/fs/cifs/SecurityFlags.
[57392.897935] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -95
```

My fstab entry:

```
//192.168.101.5/Development/Repositories /mnt/ServerName/Development/Repositories cifs credentials=/home/dev/.smbcredentials,uid=dev,gid=dev,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

I've got another entry in fstab that is nearly identical and is also mounting a Windows share -- but it's not resulting in an error.

Another question: where would I find documentation for that return code?

This error has only popped up since I went from 32 bbit Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) to 64 bit Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). The fstab entry was fine in 32 bit.

Edit: removing `sec=ntlm` seems to have fixed it, and I have no idea why. Is there an answer for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like removing `sec=ntlm` from the fstab entry fixed it.

Comment: Works in CentOS 7, too. Thanks a lot for the answer.